# Failed to send log data to elastisearch via logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I'm new to ELK, when I tried to transfer log data using logstash is not working.I'm using
docker for ELK stack and log generated via a python script.pls check logstash.conf :

```
input {
        udp {
            port => 5959
            codec => json 
            }
    }
    output {
           stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
                }
            elasticsearch {
                  hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                  index => "logdb" 
                  }
            }
```

logs generated from following py script:

```
import logging
    import logstash
    class CustomLogStashLogger:

    def __init__(self, logger_name='demo-py-logger', host='0.0.0.0', udp=5959):

        self.logger_name = logger_name
        self.host = host
        self.udp_port = udp

    def get(self):
        logging.basicConfig(
            filename="logfile",
            filemode="a",
            format="%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
            datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
            level=logging.INFO,
        )

        self.stderrLogger = logging.StreamHandler()
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.stderrLogger)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.logger_name)
        self.logger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(self.host,
                                                        self.udp_port,
                                                        version=1))
        return self.logger
    logger_instance = CustomLogStashLogger(udp=5959, host='localhost',logger_name='akhil')
    logger = logger_instance.get()

    count = 0
       #from time import sleep
    for i in range(0, 10):
        count = count + 1

        if count % 2 == 0:
          logger.error('Error Message Code Faield :{} '.format(count))
       else:
          logger.info('python-logstash: test logstash info message:{} '.format(count))
```

ElK stack is running on dockers. I got my logstash container log message that listening to port 5959

> [2022-08-31T08:00:31,019][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
> [2022-08-31T08:00:31,039][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ][main][ba85faa6d462179e21c318cb3447f81446e77e02b6d4d9382e62aa12b138b91a] Starting UDP listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5959"}
> [2022-08-31T08:00:31,087][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ][main][ba85faa6d462179e21c318cb3447f81446e77e02b6d4d9382e62aa12b138b91a] UDP listener started {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5959", :receive_buffer_bytes=>"106496", :queue_size=>"2000"}
> [2022-08-31T08:00:31,328][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your logstash logs, but there is in your python configuration, you cannot use the `host` as `0.0.0.0` in your python script, this should be the IP of your Logstash server.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks, it's working, I inspect logstash container passes its IP as parameter in pyscript

Comment: Can you mention the changes u made to fix this ?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar  inspect my logstash container and copied it's ip address and change it instead of host=0.0.0.0

Comment: Post this as the answer as well.